# Writing a proxy for an android application

Tags: java, android, proxy

I have an android application which sends information to a server in particular it sends some stats to check the normal use that users do with the app. For example if they click a button to see a specific page a stat is sent to the server specifying a series of informations like the model of the phone, the page requested, the version of android ecc ecc. These informations are later visible using splunk http://www.splunk.com/. Now my problem is, for each event sent by my app, I should be able to say if the event was correclty sent to the server or not. My idea is to develop a proxy that can intercept the requests made by my app to the server and listen the response, like Charles proxy does. The problem is I don't know where to start. Anyone can suggest me how could accomplish this task? Thanks

Comment: "I should be able to say if the event was correclty sent to the server or not."

What does "correctly sent" mean here? 
Also, how does your application sends stats to the server? Using HTTP ?

Comment: Sorry, means that I have a request structured following an inner standard and I have the response from the server and yes I use HTTP.

Comment: *As I understood you:* 1. You have an app which sends HTTP requests to server 2. You have to check that all fields that you need are filled right *Solution:* 1. Implement a proxy in your app 2. Check request in your proxy locally before send it 3. Inform your user and don't send request if it's filled wrong 4. If it's filled right... Just send it without any changes

Comment: Your requirements seem artificial or incomplete. If it really is your app, then you can make a small modification to check server responses -- if the analytics framework is designed properly, that'll be one change. A proxy is much more complex, and if you're dealing with https (which I would presume you are), then the proxy can't inspect the traffic anyway. Is it really your app you're trying to track?

Comment: Well is of the company I work for, I have been asked if I can create a proxy to monitor the traffic which will be used by automated tester, for this reason I have to consider the app as a black box. Why do you say that can't inspect the traffic anyway? maybe I am ignorant, I am only trying to figure out how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you could add code to your application so that, when you send your data, you get the HTTP reply and check if code is 200 (Which stand for OK responde from server).
If so you know that your request went fine, if not(different reply code) you treat it as an error.

You will have to check if your server is responding properly, for an error and an OK message.

See also [HTTP STATUS CODES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

A good idea would be to use the [Proxy Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for your extra code.

Comment: I need to consider my application as a black box, so I don't want to modify my code. I wanted to create an external android service(proxy) that can monitoring the flow between the client (my app) and the server, also because I want to write automated tests that use this service to monitor the traffic. For example I launch a test (using robotium) that has to click on a button, and I know that clicking on this button an event is sent to the server. Using my external service I'd like to automatcly check the request and the response to follow the internel standard.

Comment: If you want to do suck thing(capture another process request and intercept) I am guessing you will have to Root your phone/tablet.

Also, if your application cant change, I mean, you cant add new code to it, then you have a big problem. The only thing we know for sure is that there will always be changes in our software